# Android Studio - Using retrofit2 to get info from restdb

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, restdb

I'm trying to use Retrofit2 to create a GET petition for my Android app. I have followed a tutorial on how to create the code and it worked with a webpage that did not need any authentication. Then I tried to adapt the same code to my needs, but I can't get it right. Either I get a 401 error or I get a 500 error.

I want to reach this URL: `http://adaptai-eea8.restdb.io/rest/usuarios`
So my baseurl is `http://adaptai-eea8.restdb.io/`.
This is my function, which is in the MainActivity:

```
private void find(String codigo){
    String apikey = "9dc3afb8b6087192d5e9e50c5f2cb44927be5";

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://adaptai-eea8.restdb.io/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    UsuarioAPI usuarioAPI = retrofit.create(UsuarioAPI.class);
    Call<Usuario> call = usuarioAPI.find(codigo);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Usuario>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Usuario> call, Response<Usuario> response) {
            try {
                int a = 5;
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Usuario u = response.body();
                    textView.setText(u.getContra());
                    Log.d("Funciona", u.getContra());
                }


            }catch(Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Usuario> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the GET petition I am using:

```
    @Headers({"User-Agent: my-restdb-app","Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "x-apikey: heregoestheapikey", "Accept: application/json", "cache-control: no-cache"})
//@FormUrlEncoded
@GET("rest/usuarios/")
//public Call<Usuario> find(@Query("nombre") String nombre);
Call<Usuario> find(@Query("nombre") String nombre);
```

There has to be something wrong with this code, and maybe it is related to sending the apikey as a header, i don't know. Can someone tell me where am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the apiKey as header you need to pass it as a parameter like you can see in the [docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Header.html)

```
@Headers({"User-Agent: my-restdb-app","Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept: application/json", "cache-control: no-cache"})
@GET("rest/usuarios/")
Call<Usuario> find(@Header("x-apikey") String apiKey, @Query("nombre") String nombre);
```

Additionally, are you sure about the rest of parameters? Like User-Agent being "my-restdb-app" and query param name being "nombre"

Comment: Hi, I am not sure at all about the headers. I've been trying a lot of combinations, and also I've tried copying the same headers as in Postman (I can access the database with Postman without any problem). And yes, the Query should be ok.Is there an easier or more correct way of connecting my app to an online database? I can migrate to any other type of database, I just need it to be "easy" to program.